# How do I use partman preseed answers to select partition #3?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, virtualization

I'm trying to use a preseed file to install ubuntu onto a VM that already is partitioned using a python script. The VM stores multiple OS using MBR. I need to access the partition #3, set the mountpoint to / and then save changes and write to disk since I cannot proceed till the partition #3 has a root directory, otherwise it throws an error.

```
d-i partman-auto/method string regular    #Go to Manual Partitioning
```

<**Add lines for selecting partitioning #3 and adding mountpoint { / }**  >

The following code is to save changes to disk:

```
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true

d-i partman/choose_partition select finish

d-i partman/confirm boolean true

d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

d-i partman/confirm_nochanges boolean true
```

Please help me out, I've been stuck for 2 days.

Please check this image to get more context of my problem:
[Manual Partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIH3T.png)

Comment: What VM software are you using? What is the host OS?

Comment: Virtualbox and Ubuntu 16.04 Server.